# ArcMap 10.2.2 Creating two random points approximately 50 meters apart

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I am fairly new to ArcMap 10.2.2 so please bear with me. I am trying to create ten sets of two random points approximately 50 meters apart within a polygon restraining feature.

Edit:

Minimum distance is not a factor, I simply need 10 sets of 2 random points. Each set of two points being exactly 50 meters apart

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this but say your first set of 2 points are created 50m apart then the second set get created which will be 50m apart from each other but how close can they be to the existing set of points and then all combinations? Once a set of points have been placed do these act as an exclusion zone to ALL other sets of points or are each set independent of each other?

Comment: Minimum distance is not a factor, I simply need 10 sets of 2 random points. Each set of two points being exactly 50 meters apart

Answer (score 3):

Just incase you don't have Advanced licensing, or Spatial/3D Analyst extensions, I've created a geoproccessing tool that will generate random points within a polygon boundary with the ability to set a minimum distance between points.

You can download the toolbox, and see the source code here: [click me](http://ianbroad.com/arcgis-toolbox-generate-random-points-arcpy/)

Here's a screenshot of the parameters:

[image]

You would just want to select the input polygon feature class, enter 2 for number of random points, and put 50 for the minimum distance. You can also set this tool up to run in batch mode.